# Organizar botones en navbar de bootstrap 4 cuando aparece menu de hamburguesa

Tags: menú, bootstrap-4, responsive, nav

Necesito organizar los botones en el navbar de bootstrap 4 cuando aparece menú de hamburguesa al colapsarse, aquí es como esta normalmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego al colapsarse para la versión responsive:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como Podría colocar los elementos hacia abajo alineados respecto al menu de hamburguesa?.
Este es mi código:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top ">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa d-inline fa-lg fa-cloud"></i><b> Marca </b></a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">

      <li class="nav-item ">
        <div class="custom-switch">
          <input class="custom-switch-input" id="ADD_ID_HERE" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label class="custom-switch-btn" for="ADD_ID_HERE"></label>
          <div class="custom-switch-content-checked text-center" style="color:white; ">
            Vasdas 
          </div>
          <div class="custom-switch-content-unchecked text-center"  style="color:white;">
            Nasdasd
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="btn navbar-btn ml-2 text-white"><i class="fa d-inline fa-lg fa-user-circle-o"></i> Supervisor </a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center my-2">
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_cosdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Casdsadasd</button></div>
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_devsdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Dasdasd</button></div>
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_pasdfsd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Pasdasd</button></div>
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_ssdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Sasdasd</button></div>
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_tsdfsdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Tadasdasdas</button></div>
          <div class="p-2"><button class="btn btn-info" id="btn_vsfsd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Vadasdasdas</button></div>
      </div>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="2348884adas" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="buscar" type="submit"><i class="material-icons">search</i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: hehehe me llamó la atención por lo de "hamburguesa".

Comment: pero los quieres en una sola columna hacia abajo o en línea con la "hamburguesa"

Comment: Es muy ambiguo que digas que lo quieres organizado. Eso depende del punto de vista de cada persona. Define exactamente como quieres que se vea

Comment: Disculpen por no ser explicito, intento que cuando se despliegue el menú de hamburguesa los elementos queden en linea hacia abajo con el, creo que seria la forma mas cómoda para poder seguir usando la interfaz en pantallas pequeñas